# HTML: Define the action of "enter" in a <form>

Tags: html, forms, button

I've got an HTML `<form>` with a few `<button>`s and an `<input type="submit">`:

```
<form>
    <button>first button</button>
    <button>second button</button>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed while in the `text` field, the "first button" is activated instead of the "submit" button.

How can I make <kbd>enter</kbd> trigger the "submit" button?

Comment: Do you want pure HTML or is JavaScript OK?

Comment: I'm hoping for pure HTML — I know I could do it with JS, but if it can be done with just HTMl, that's probably better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default behavior of a `<button>` element is to act like a 'submit' button. Try using `<button type='button'>` for the non-submit buttons.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. That's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for, but couldn't find. Thanks! Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score -2):

You can most likely override he default behavior of your text-input via some simple [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Try taking a look at the documentation for [.keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)